# Integrate Qr code with sencha touch

Tags: sencha-touch-2, barcode, phonegap-plugins

I need to implement a qr code to  my sencha touch project. 
Here is the tutorial that I used to follow.
http://simonmacdonald.blogspot.com/2011/12/installing-barcode-plugin-for-phonegap.html

I follow the tutorial and the phonegap plugins is working very well in my  phone. But nw I got a question. Hw can I customise the layout and implement the plugin to  my sencha touch project?

For example when i click **member profile button** a bar code scanner will appear.

Here is my code.

```
Ext.define('bluebutton.view.BlueButton.MemberPopUp', {
extend: 'Ext.Panel',
xtype: 'memberpopup',

requires: [
    'Ext.form.Panel',
    'Ext.form.FieldSet',
    'Ext.field.Text',
     'bluebutton.view.BlueButton.MemberDetail'

],

config: {


    items: [
                 {
                     docked: 'top',
                     xtype: 'titlebar',
                     items: [
                         {
                             xtype: 'button',
                             text: 'Member Profile'
                         },
                          {
                              xtype: 'button',
                              text: 'Transaction History'
                          }
                      ]
                 },
                 {
                    html : '<div align="center"> <img src="/bluebutton/resources/images/user2.png" alt="Smiley face" height="150" width="150" border="5"> </div>'


                 }
             ]

}
```

});

Please help. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

1) you can use **navigation view**

Ex:

```
var view = Ext.create('Ext.NavigationView', {
fullscreen: true,

items: [{
    title: 'First',
    items: [{
        xtype: 'button',
        text: 'Push a new view!',
        handler: function() {
            //use the push() method to push another view. It works much like
            //add() or setActiveItem(). it accepts a view instance, or you can give it
            //a view config.
            view.push({
                title: 'Second',
                html: 'Second view!'
            });
        }
    }]
}]
```

});

put Scanner in sencond view

or use **card layout**

put button in first item and scanner in second item
use `Ext.getCmp(cardlayoutid).animateActiveItem( Object/Number activeItem, Object/Ext.fx.layout.Card animation)` in button handler